# After upgrading ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04 I am no longer able to open Matlab 2013a

Tags: 15.04, matlab

I can't open Matlab 2013a after I upgrade Ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04. I have also tried to open from the location folder, and when I try to open it from the console using $

```
$ cd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/
$ ./matlab
```

I get the following message.

[image]

Comment: Did you click Details to see if it had more info about the problem Matlab encountered? Did you send the error report to MathWorks?

Comment: Yes, I get Segmentation Violation Detected.

Comment: If there's more info in the details, please edit your question to include the full details. Please also be sure to report the error to MathWorks if you haven't already done so.

Comment: So I ended up removing MATLAB 2013a, and I have installed MATLAB 2014b. I couldn't find a solution, and I need to have MATLAB for performing a simulation.

Comment: This is also the problem and removing the jayatana package the solution w.r.t. Matlab R2012b on Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the following line from your message, you have the `jayatana` package installed:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
```

This package is responsible for application menu support for Java swing applications, and seems to be the cause for the segfault. Removing it worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove jayatana
```

Don't forget to restart your session afterwards as the package installs the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable. Or try it from a terminal window:

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS= /path/to/your/matlab
```

Comment: I guees it would have worked, but I have deleted all files related to MATLAB 2013a. However, thank you Seebicah.

Comment: Removing the `jayatana` package works for me.

Answer (score 13):

I was having the same problem, I guess from the error messages that it was due to the the old libc libraries used by Matlab.

I installed the packages `matlab-support` and `matlab-support-dev` and things started to work.

One more thing: Chose to rename the old GCC libraries form MATLAB and use the new ones from Ubuntu when asked!!!

Comment: This works for me with MATLAB 2015b on Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: works for me with R2016a on Ubuntu16.04lts

Answer (score 0):

One stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293956/segmentation-violation-detected-matlab) showed that segmentation violation error can be solved by changing the default renderer to `zbuffer`. Add this line to the `startup.m` file:

> set(0, 'DefaultFigureRenderer', 'zbuffer');

Comment: It does not work. I have gotten the following message:
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Segmentation violation detected at Wed Apr 29 18:03:36 2015
If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/
Thank you for your help.** This crash report has been saved to disk as /home/m/matlab_crash_dump.9070-1 **
MATLAB is exiting because of fatal error
Killed

Comment: I had to add that I have updated JDK 7 to 8, so because of my error is related with java, I wonder if this is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to unset the environment variable causing the problem before running Matlab.  Seems to work so far without side effects:

```
$ unset JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
$ matlab
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, graphics card(Nvidia) was a problem. Try switching to default graphics. Then reboot your system and run matlab.

Comment: Hi @SundeepJoshi you say: "Try switching to default graphics" - how? Maybe you should edit your answer to include instructions on how to switch to default graphics.