# Matlab crashes on start after upgrading to 15.04 (from 14.10) [works as sudo]

Tags: permissions, 15.04, crash, matlab

I recently upgraded to 15.04 and immediately after, Matlab 2012b no longer worked and crashed either as soon as it loads the program, or a few moments after I try to do anything.  I tried installing a newer version of Matlab, 2013a, but the issue remains.

I've seen one or two other [posts similar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615644/after-upgrading-ubuntu-14-10-to-15-04-i-am-no-longer-able-to-open-matlab-2013a), but they seem to be related to java, and I don't think this is the case for me (I could be wrong!), and I'm not entirely sure how to find the specific issue from the error message.

The error message says `MATLAB has encountered an internal problem and needs to close.`

and here's the details for the message:

```
MATLAB crash file:/home/james/matlab_crash_dump.10850-1:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Segmentation violation detected at Sun Aug 30 22:37:24 2015
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding     : Disabled
  Current Visual     : 0x20 (class 4, depth 24)
  Default Encoding   : UTF-8
  GNU C Library      : 2.21 stable
  MATLAB Architecture: glnxa64
  MATLAB Root        : /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a
  MATLAB Version     : 8.1.0.604 (R2013a)
  Operating System   : Linux 3.19.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 11 14:16:32 UTC 2015 x86_64
  Processor ID       : x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 6, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine    : Java 1.6.0_17-b04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System      : The X.Org Foundation (11701000), display :0

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Segmentation violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 00007f2cde2cb9b0  RBX = 00007f2ccc09cb20
  RCX = 00007f2cda656da0  RDX = 00000000fffffffd
  RSP = 00007f2cda656d40  RBP = 00007f2ccc03ed80
  RSI = 00007f2ccc09cb20  RDI = 00007f2c00000000

   R8 = 00007f2ccc075108   R9 = 00007f2cde83f2a0
  R10 = 00007f2cde83f300  R11 = 000000000000000b
  R12 = 00000000fffffffd  R13 = 00007f2ccc02b1d0
  R14 = 00007f2cda656da0  R15 = 0000000000000004

  RIP = 00007f2cec0d1c84  EFL = 0000000000010202

   CS = 0033   FS = 0000   GS = 0000

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00007f2cec0d1c84              /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+00040068 pthread_mutex_lock+00000004
[  1] 0x00007f2cde2bbbc1              /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6+00109505 XFindContext+00000097
[  2] 0x00007f2cdebbc388 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libXm.so.3+01483656 _XmGetWidgetExtData+00000056
[  3] 0x00007f2cdebb546b /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libXm.so.3+01455211 _XmGetFocusPolicy+00000059
[  4] 0x00007f2cdebb65bd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libXm.so.3+01459645 _XmManagerFocusOut+00000061
[  5] 0x00007f2cde6213ae               /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6+00291758
[  6] 0x00007f2cde6217f4               /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6+00292852
[  7] 0x00007f2cde622620               /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6+00296480 _XtTranslateEvent+00001568
[  8] 0x00007f2cde5fbc9b               /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6+00138395 XtDispatchEventToWidget+00001115
[  9] 0x00007f2cde5fcaf2               /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6+00142066 _XtSendFocusEvent+00000210
[ 10] 0x00007f2cde5fbc4b               /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6+00138315 XtDispatchEventToWidget+00001035
[ 11] 0x00007f2cde5fc348               /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6+00140104
[ 12] 0x00007f2cde5fc499               /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6+00140441 XtDispatchEvent+00000201
[ 13] 0x00007f2cde6079be               /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6+00186814 XtAppProcessEvent+00000734
[ 14] 0x00007f2ce1ad34d3   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwuix.so+00480467
[ 15] 0x00007f2ce1ae0df2   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwuix.so+00536050
[ 16] 0x00007f2cee639862 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+01845346
[ 17] 0x00007f2cee63a50f /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+01848591 _Z25svWS_ProcessPendingEventsiib+00001615
[ 18] 0x00007f2cedf4f5ef   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00316911
[ 19] 0x00007f2cedf4ff5c   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00319324
[ 20] 0x00007f2cedf49592   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00292242
[ 21] 0x00007f2cec0cf6aa              /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+00030378
[ 22] 0x00007f2cebe04eed                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+01076973 clone+00000109


If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.

Thank you for your help.
```

And ideas as to what might be causing this error?  I tried installing the matlab-support package from apt-get, but it seemed not to solve it.

--------------------------------UPDATE------------------------
I had another go at the issue, and I discovered that Matlab does now work when I use `sudo` and launch from terminal.  This is pretty strange, as I didn't have to use `sudo` before the 15.04 upgrade.

I've tried to fix this by changing the chown of the matlab installation directory and the `.matlab` to my username, but no luck.  So it looks like the upgrade to 15.04 resulted in a permissions error.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?  Having to use `sudo` for each launch means I can't use `.desktop` launchers for matlab, which makes things inconvenient...  any ideas?

Comment: Matlab isn't open source, I suppose. So, the only simple option is to report this on their bug tracker. Also it can be useful to run it under `valgrind` to see what was incorrectly accessed.

Comment: I'll give valgrind a try if i dont see any solutions in the next few days, but im worried it might be a bit above my skill level. I was hoping that this would be a common issue with a fix as simple as installing some missing packages, but looks like I'm the only one experiencing the issue :(

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely the bug described [here](https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1297894), that is, an incompatibility between stdlibc++ versions.

Workaround, from the Mathworks support thread linked above:

> 1. Identify the location where MATLAB is installed
> 2. Navigate to the sys/os/glnxa64 directory within this installation folder
> 3. Rename libstdc++.so.6 library to libstdc++.so.6.old

It worked for me, at least.